# Latex L3 Programming Layer Interface using \_ and \__

Tags: expl3

I have been looking at style files using the L3 Programming Layer Interface for Latex in which people use `\_` and `\__`.  What is their purpose, are they standard indicators for specific things or simply an individual style?

I have also seen things like `galex/theorem`.  When are things with `/` used?

Comment: this is documented in 3.2.1 Separating private and public material in expl3.pdf which you get with texdoc expl3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private functions (macros) are explicitly marked in `expl3` code: they start `\__...`. In the same way, private variables should be called `\l__..`/`\g__..` with two underscores, not one. This is a simple way to ensure that it is clear which parts of a module can be used by others: only the public interfaces.